# Why is an odd link tag receiving an even tag's css property?

Tags: html, css

An odd link tag is receiving an even tag's css property of margin-right. I have triple-checked the tags and it is indeed an odd element on the bottom left row (labeled [Live]). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
HTML:

```
    <div className="thumbnails">
      <span className="question">A selection of work I have pushed into the Github ether:</span><br />
      <img src="./images/entente-logo.png" />
      <img src="./images/ski-free-grab.png" />
      <img src="./images/instapixies-grab.png" />
      <br />
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <br />
      <img src="./images/secretsnowman-grab.png" />
      <img src="./images/gameoflife-grab.png" />
      <span className="curly-brax">&#123;An_ORM&#125;</span>
      <br />
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#" /><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#" /><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <br />
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.thumbnails a:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.thumbnails a {
  width: 110px;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

[[image: There is a margin right of 40px 1]]

Comment: Can you provide the HTML please?

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er2LLgf1/) with the most basic sense of your code that seems to be working as intended. It's likely you have styling happening from someplace else. `even` won't voluntarily style an odd nth-child.

Comment: So which `odd` `<a>` element do you think is getting `even` margins?

Comment: Also, `className` isn't a valid HTML attribute for css targeting. `<a href="#" />` isn't valid HTML syntax.

Comment: @Zader Ahh okay, that makes sense and is kind of important information. ;)

Comment: It's in React :) Sorry deleted my original comment, and to relieve future viewers from becoming confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your odd anchor tags are receiving the margin is because the `:nth-child(even)` pseudo-selector is going to count even elements relative to the parent regardless of the element type.

So since you have numerous elements that are not `a` elements within the parent `.thumbnails`, The selector is going to select every even element within the parent, `.thumbnails`, check if it is an `a` tag and if it is: add the margin.

In order to achieve what you are trying, you will either need to add a unique class to all "even" anchor elements or place the `a` tags in a containing element which only contains the `a` tags.

Consider trying something like this:

HTML:

```
<div className="thumbnails">
  <span className="question">A selection of work I have pushed into the Github ether:</span><br />
  <img src="./images/entente-logo.png" />
  <img src="./images/ski-free-grab.png" />
  <img src="./images/instapixies-grab.png" />
  <br />
  <div class="anchorList">
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <img src="./images/secretsnowman-grab.png" />
  <img src="./images/gameoflife-grab.png" />
  <span className="curly-brax">&#123;An_ORM&#125;</span>
  <br />
  <div class="anchorList">
      <a href="#">[Live]</a><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#" /><a href="#">[Code]</a>
      <a href="#" /><a href="#">[Code]</a>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnails .anchorList a:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.thumbnails .anchorList a {
    width: 110px;
    height: 42px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```